# how do i call captureScreenshot method for reporting a bug?

Tags: selenium

My following code displayed 5 tooltip list only, actually 6 tooltips are there. System.out.println(contactTooltipList.size()) giving the size 6.

```
public void clickOnContacts()
    {
        log.info("Clicked on 'Contacts' tab option and Tooltips are: "); 
        System.out.println(contactTooltipList.size());
        contactDropDown.click();
         Iterator<WebElement> itr= contactTooltipList.iterator();
            while(itr.hasNext()) {
                String toolTips = itr.next().getText();
                toolTips=toolTips.replaceAll("\n", " ");
                System.out.println(toolTips);
            }

         System.out.println("\n");
    }
```

The first tooltip(Address) is missing, above code has displayed the tooltips from 2 to 5 as shown below:

```
Home: (111) 222-3333
Mobile: (500) 000-0000
Email: xxxxxxxxx...
Secondary Language -
Preferred Unknown
```

I would like to report as bug by capturing the screenshot as displayed tooltips are not as per size. 
How do i call captureScreenshot method? Or how do i report it's a bug?

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can take a screenshot as such:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
// add the above imports

File screenshotFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
```

Now that you have `screenshotFile` stored, you can do whatever you need with it -- such as save it to your system:

```
FileUtils.copyFile(screenshotFile, new File("C:/Path/where/to/save/screenshot));
```